# What does pr -m -t means?

Tags: linux, options, pr

What does `pr -m -t` mean? I managed to find out that `-t` suppresses headers and footers. What does `-m` mean specifically?

Comment: `man pr` on your server should tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pr -m`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html) merges the files it’s processing, one per column:

```
$ pr -m <(seq 1 100) <(seq 101 200) | head


2021-11-30 15:16                                                  Page 1


1                                   101
2                                   102
3                                   103
4                                   104
5                                   105
```